# Having/being a sweet tooth

Tags: idioms, colloquial-language

Several times I came across the expression "I *am* a sweet tooth", not "I *have* a sweet tooth".
Is it allowable in colloquival speech?

[Example 1](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20141022225256-326043733-are-you-a-sweet-tooth-i-m-afraid-i-am-but-there-are-ways-around-it-so-you-can-stay-slim-healthy-and-happy)

[Example 2](https://ru.pinterest.com/birgitschack/are-you-a-sweet-tooth/)

[Example 3](http://www.downsizeme.net.au/are-you-a-sweet-tooth/)

Comment: I don't think I have ever heard someone say "I am a sweet tooth", but I have heard "I have a sweet tooth" many times. Where have you been coming across "I am a sweet tooth", could you link to some examples? I bet they are not from native speakers.

Comment: An example is attached.

Comment: Well, the person is a native speaker, but I don't think that's correct. I certainly can't vouch for the quality of the science in the rest of the article.

Comment: All three of those examples are in web page titles. Just because a few people entitle a quiz "Are you a sweet tooth?" doesn't mean the sentence "I am a sweet tooth" is common. (I'd argue it isn't.)

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: If you look at [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+sweet+tooth%2Chas+a+sweet+tooth%2Cbe+a+sweet+tooth%2Cam+a+sweet+tooth%2Cis+a+sweet+tooth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20sweet%20tooth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20a%20sweet%20tooth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20sweet%20tooth%3B%2Cc0), you'll see that "have a sweet tooth" or "has a sweet tooth" is far more common than "is a sweet tooth" or "am a sweet tooth".  They mean exactly the same thing, but **have** will sound much more natural to native speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not natural English, but that doesn't mean you couldn't use it for humorous effect.  This relates to the concept of [*metaphor*](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/metaphor-examples.html), where you relate the characteristics of two objects.

> He is *a real mule* when he doesn't get his way.  He digs in his heels and no one can move him.
>
> The University is a *beacon of hope* for those who aspire to an advanced degree but lack sufficient funds, since it doesn't charge any tuition and provides a living stipend for underprivileged students.

In the same way you could have the following conversation:

> A. I confess, I have a serious sweet tooth.
>   B. That's nothing. I *am* a sweet tooth!

The suggestion here is that you have such a weakness for sweet foods that you can be *described* as a "sweet tooth".  But, again, this is just a clever metaphor, and not a common idiom.